# WebApi POST body not binding with FromBody

Tags: asp.net-apicontroller, frombodyattribute

I've defined my ApiController's method like so:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] string json)
```

The method is being called, but json is always null.  I can see via Fiddler that what I'm passing is what I expect (hostname obviously edited out).  What am I missing here?

> POST http://somehost.com/api/somemethod HTTP/1.1
>   User-Agent: Fiddler
>   Host: somehost.com
>   Content-Length: 54
>   Content-Type: application/json
>
> {"site":"home","region":"region","flags":"flags"}